# how to add popup window for long texts Android

Tags: android, text, popup, dialog

How to write a long text in a pop up window. I tried this `dlgAlert.setMessage("Long Text");` but it is not good for long text's like descriptions. i want a new popup window with long text and OK button, so that users can read the text without any problem. how can i do this ?

Comment: Post the full example of what you've tried.

Comment: This is not a place to post questions like "How to", "Code this for me", "How can I achieve this" - Please try, and show us what you tried in a format called sourcecode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an AlertDialog:

```
    String loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam";

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("My Title");
    builder.setMessage(loremIpsum);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Which will look like this(It scrolls):

[image]